# redux-observable testing forkJoin marble diagram

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm somehow struggling to come up with marble diagram when using `forkJoin`. My output somehow always says that subscription is empty.

Pseudo code:

```
// epic
const epic = (action$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType('SAVE'),
  mergeMap(() => {
    const requests = [
      getJSON('/a'),
      getJSON('/b'),
      getJSON('/c'),
    ];
    return forkJoin(
      ...requests
    ).pipe(
      mergeMap(() => [
        { type: 'SAVE_DONE'},
        { type: 'LOAD'},
      ])
    );
  })
);

// mock
const dependencies = {
  getJSON: url => cold('g', {
    g: { url }
  })
};

// input
hot('i', {
  i: { type: 'SAVE' }
} 
// output??
```

forkJoin goes in parallel, but in marble diagram it's sequential ? `ggg` ? Cause afaik if we look a the whole flow it's `igggxy` where x and y are the `SAVE_DONE` and `LOAD` actions. Or am I completely misunderstanding this?

Comment: That's all weird. `forkJoin` only emits when all its source Observables emit at least once and complete. You're using `cold('g')` which means this Observable never completes. You'd have to change it to `cold('(g|)')`, If you could make a stackblitz demo that would help.

Comment: Perfect! thank you :) this, together with expected `(ab)` works fine. Can you explain a bit more about how complete operator helps here?

Comment: I think there's not much to explain. `forkJoin` requires all source Observables to complete so that's why `|` is important.

Comment: When you have `(a|)`, it means the source will sent the **value** and will **complete** within the **same frame**; essentially it means: `subscriber.next('a'); subscriber.complete()`.

Answer (score 0):

if the test of `epic` you should expect 2 emits of `SAVE_DONE` and `LOAD` one right after another, for that you need parentheses.

Then the diagram should look like:

```js
cold('(ab)', {
    a: { type: 'SAVE_DONE'},
    b: { type: 'LOAD'},
  })
};
```

for the dependency of `getJSON` is up to you, there you can actually to simulate errors, or delays in the load, the longest is the winner.

```js
const dependencies = {
  getJSON: url =>
    url === '/a'
      ? cold('--a|', {
        a: { url }
      }) :
    url === '/b'
      ? cold('---a|', {
        a: { url }
      }) :
    url === '/c'
      ? cold('----a|', {
        a: { url }
      }) :
    cold('|', {}),
};
```

and because we have delay of 40ms the main diagram should be like

```js
cold('----(ab)', {
    a: { type: 'SAVE_DONE'},
    b: { type: 'LOAD'},
  })
};
```